LCD_TFT HSYNC | LCDTFT VSYNC | LCD_TFT DE
I have a 320*240 LCD with an ili9341 driver that I want to drive using the LTDC unit of a microcontroller. However, according to the datasheet, my LCD does not have VSYNC, HSYNC, and DE pins. Can you please help me?
datasheet
enter link description here

Well, which LCD module you have then, and what pins does it have? We don't know what help you need if you want to do something that is not possible. Also which MCU you have and what pins does the "LTDC" unit has and what it is?
